# Swagger with play 2

Tags: java, playframework, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-play2

did anyone tried using swagger with play 2.
i have play 2 java project and i am trying to integrate swagger with it without any luck.
i installed the package using this dependency:

```
"com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.3.7"
```

but i keep getting this error from the routes file:

```
object ApiHelpController is not a member of package controllers
In C:\play project\check8s-api\conf\routes at line 21.

line 21: GET      /api-docs.json                controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources
```

any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Can you provide your `build.sbt` file? Also have you run `play update`/`activator update`?

Comment: got it solved the route was wrong. thanks

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I am getting the same error, what was your solution?

Comment: 1. Check if you properly added the play.module.enabled in application.conf
2. Check that your package structure wont conflict with controllers.ApiHelpController
3. I added the /api-docs.json route and it did not work, after i closed and opened IntelliJ the route file got interpreted correctly and i was able to compile the project

Comment: how did you resolve the non-static controller issue?

Comment: Play 2 means 2.0 ?